# NSB AppStudio - Image not showing from local storage

Tags: javascript

I have a form that takes in two text inputs and one image input **(PictureBox)**. I can get the text inputs to show from local storage but I can't get the image to show. I have read the official docs but to no avail.

**Form 1**

```
NSBPage.appendChild(HeaderGlobal)
Button1.onclick=function(){
   var myDetails1 = Input1.value;
   var myDetails2 = Input1Copy.value;
 localStorage.myDetails1 = PictureBox1.toDataURL();
 console.log(localStorage);
 
 $("#Toast1").toast("show");
 Form1.reset();
 ChangeForm(Form2)
}
```

[image: LocalStorage]

**Form 2**

```
Form2.onshow=function(){
    if(localStorage.myDetails1){
    
    localStorage.setItem("myDetails1",localStorage.myDetails1);
    const recentImageDataUrl = localStorage.getItem("myDetails1");
    if(recentImageDataUrl){
    PictureBox2.setAttribute("src",recentImageDataUrl);
    }
}

Button1Copy.onclick=function(){
  ChangeForm(Form1);
}
```

Comment: `var im = localStorage.myDetails1; var im;` ?

Answer (score 0):

[Local/Session Storage - JavaScript Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8K2ihr3NC40&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified)

With help from this video and a few modification I finally got it to work.

**Post 2**

```
Form2.onshow=function(){
    if(localStorage.myDetails1){
    
    localStorage.setItem("myDetails1",localStorage.myDetails1);
    const recentImageDataUrl = localStorage.getItem("myDetails1");
    if(recentImageDataUrl){
    Image1.src = recentImageDataUrl;
   
    }

  
  }
}
```